# Impala open connection in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, connection, impala

I'm after a way of querying Impala through Python which enables you to keep a connection open and pass queries to it.

I can connect quite happily to Impala using this sort of code:

```
import subprocess
sql = 'some sort of sql statement;'
cmds = ['impala-shell','-k','-B','-i','impala.company.corp','-q', sql]
out,err = subprocess.Popen(cmds, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print(out.decode())
print(err.decode())
```

I can also switch out the `-q` and sql for `-f` and a file with sql statements as per the documentation [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-13-x/topics/impala_impala_shell.html).

When I'm running this for multiple sql statements the name node it uses is the same for all the queries and it it will stop if there is a failure in the code (unless I use the option to continue), this is all expected.

What I'm trying to get to is where I can run a query or two, check the results using some python logic and then continue if it meets my criteria.
I have tried splitting up my code into individual queries using sqlparse and running them one by one. This works well in isolation but if one statement is a `drop table if exists x;` and the next one then goes `create table x (blah string);` then if x did actually exist then because the second statement will run on a different node the dropping metadata change hasn't reached that one yet and it fails with `table x already exists` or similar error.

I'd think as well as getting round this metadata issue it would just make more sense to keep a connection open to impala whilst I run all the statements but I'm struggling to work this out.
Does anyone have any code that has this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanna look at [impyla](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla), the Impala/Hive python client, if you haven't done so already.

As far as the second part of your question, using Impala's [SYNC_DDL](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_sync_ddl.html) option will guarantee that DDL changes are propagated across `impalad`s before next DDL is executed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the sync_ddl bit as a first stop. Will feedback after some testing on Monday.

Comment: The sync_ddl definitely solved the issue. I'm sure this should still be possible to have an interactive impala-shell session and pass things through subprocess. But for now the hassle of working it out outweighs the benefits of being able to see how the query is doing in realtime rather than at the end.